# Select only items that have children from MySql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table that contains records with a parent > child relationship:

*my_table*

| id | pid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Item 1 |
| 2 | 0 | Item 2 |
| 3 | 1 | Child item 1 |
| 4 | 1 | Child item 2 |
| 5 | 1 | Child item 3 |

I'm trying to write a query that selects all items that have one or more children.

```
SELECT my_table.* 
FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM my_table AS t2 
    WHERE t2.pid=my_table.id
)
```

However, this query isn't returning what i'm expecting. It has correctly excluded "Item 2" which has no children, but instead of just returning "Item 1" it has returned all of "Item 1"'s children too:

| id | pid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Item 1 |
| 3 | 1 | Child item 1 |
| 4 | 1 | Child item 2 |
| 5 | 1 | Child item 3 |

I can get it to only return the parent by adding `AND pid=0` to my query:

```
SELECT my_table.* 
FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM my_table AS t2 
    WHERE t2.pid=my_table.id
)
AND pid=0
```

However, i'm not sure this is a proper solution and I still don't understand why the child records are returned because the `WHERE EXISTS` clause should return no results for the child rows and therfore they should be excluded.

Comment: Your query runs fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fJLCJwY6Ma2kH3UFz2ceqy/0

Comment: also the pid=0 is not a proper solution. cause you just tell it exactly who the father is. and then exclude entry 2 with your where exist. but as forpas said your query seems fine

Comment: Thanks for this @forpas. I was fixated on the query being the problem but you're right, the query works fine. My problem was actually being caused by something completely unrelated and as soon as I fixed it everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Another, slightly more verbose but IMHO easier to understand, approach.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT pid
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY pid
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 0
);
```